# With mysql_fetch_array I can easily count the rows returned. Can I do something similar with mysql_fetch_object?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysql-num-rows

(Apologies if necessary--my first Stack Overflow question. I'll be happy to modify it if anyone has suggestions. I have looked for an answer but I'm afraid my grasp of the terminology isn't good enough to make a complete search.)

I'm accustomed to using mysql_fetch_array to get records from a database.
When getting records that way, mysql_num_rows gives me a count of the rows.
On my current project, however, I'm using mysql_fetch_object.
mysql_num_rows doesn't seem to work with this function, and when I do a 'count' on the results of the query I get the expected answer: 1 (one object).

Is there a way to 'see into' the object and count the elements inside it?

Comment: nice, but you should ditch mysql_* function, replace it with mysqli, pdo (`mysqli->num_rows` is a property set to number of rows returned)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The function `mysql_num_rows` works on your result resource, not your object row.

#### Example

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");
mysql_select_db("database", $link);

$sql = "SELECT id, name FROM myTable";

$result = mysql_query($sql, $link);

$rowCount = mysql_num_rows($result);

while($row = mysql_fetch_object){
    echo "id: ".$row->id." name: ".$row->name."<BR>";
}
echo "total: ".$rowCount;
```

Comment: I think `mysql_fetch_object` in your `while()` should actually be `mysql_fetch_object($result)`

Answer (score 2):

Try `count( (array)$object )`.

Comment: This gave me a different answer. It returned the number of fields in my SELECT query.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using it in procedural style (i.e. mysql_fetch_object() vs. $result->fetch_object()), mysql_num_rows should work exactly the same way as when using mysql_fetch_array().  Could you post some sample code?

Comment: I am using it this way (in procedural style). Should I not be?

Comment: No, using it procedurally is OK.  Could you post a snippet of your code?

Comment: At this point the code has changed so much it wouldn't be relevant. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password");
mysql_select_db("database");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM table");
$countQuery = mysql_query("SELECT found_rows() AS totalRows");
$rows = mysql_fetch_object($countQuery);
echo $rows->totalRows;
?>
```

I hope this is useful :)

Comment: It's interesting (I wasn't aware of this kind of SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS), but I want to do other things besides just count the rows.